# Component Not Showing Content in React Application

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, components, react-bootstrap

I created a page in my application to display rows of cards, featuring only the title and an image. But, for some reason, the content is not showing. There are no errors and, as far as I can see, now problems with the syntax. I don't understand why my component is producing a blank page.

I've used a similar method for other pages and those worked, so I don't see where I'm going wrong here. Could somebody please help me understand why my component isn't appearing on this particular page? I'd really appreciate it.

Listed below is my code, along with a picture of how I set up my files.

[image: File Setup]

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/navbar.js';
import Footer from './components/Footer/footer.js';
import Home from './pages/Home/home.js';
import Login from './pages/Login/login.js';
import Languages from './pages/Languages/languages.js';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar/>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
            <Route path="/languages" component={Languages}/>
          </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Languages.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LangCard from "../../components/LangCard/langcard.js";
import './languages.css';

class Languages extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <LangCard />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Languages;
```

**LangCard.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import './langcard.css';

const LangCard = () => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row" >
                <Card id="lang-card">
                    <div className="card-img"></div>
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Card.Title>Italian</Card.Title>
                        </Card.Body>
                </Card>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default LangCard;
```

Comment: Assuming your files are all saved in TitleCase format, then in your App.js imports, should `languages.js` be capitalized (`Languages.js`), as well as `langcard.js` => `LangCard.js` in your Languages.js imports?

Comment: @thmsdnnr No, unfortunately. I tried that, but it didn't work. They're already linked correctly. My components may be uppercase, but the `js` and `css` files within each one are always lowercase. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Maybe you can share a screenshot of your folder structures?

Comment: @Isaac I just edited my post. A screenshot should be available now.